# remove description in colum title post

Tags: posts

[image: remove description post]

I encountered a problem in the wordpress admin.in Post-> all post.it born a description that I wanted to give it.can i help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On same page above post list (in top right), you have this section to change list view.
Select the red arrow pointed option to disable excerpt view.

Currently you are in excerpt view that's why post description is showing.

[image]